# targeting elements based on order number with pseudo classes

Tags: css, pseudo-class

Imagine I have a div with a bunch of paragraphs nested inside, I want to select the second, fourth and seventh paragraph element.

I know you can use nth-child to select a nested element, but works for one only. This won't work;

```
nth-child(2,4,7)
```

How do I select multiple specific elements. Is this possible?

Thanks,

Comment: Use `p:nth-of-type(..)`, separated by a comma.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
p:nth-child(2), p:nth-child(3), p:nth-child(8)
{
    background:#000;
}
```

Comment: that helps. I realised I could do this. But was wondering if you could select multiple in the same selector but I guess that's not possible. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

read this article i hope this will help you :- http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/

you can use this method like mentioning below css so this will select every second paragraph.

```
p:nth-child(2n) {
            background:red;
            }
```

http://tinkerbin.com/8KzrmwdB